# Getting error while creating WAR file

Tags: java

```
C:\Users\accer\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Scholarshipcrud>jar cf scholarship.war

'c'` flag requires manifest or input files to be specified!
Usage: `jar {ctxui}[vfm0Me] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] fil
es ...
Options:  

-c  create new archive
-t  list table of contents for archive
-x  extract named (or all) files from archive
-u  update existing archive
-v  generate verbose output on standard output
-f  specify archive file name
-m  include manifest information from specified manifest file
-e  specify application entry point for stand-alone application
    bundled into an executable jar file
-0  store only; use no ZIP compression
-M  do not create a manifest file for the entries
-i  generate index information for the specified jar files
-C  change to the specified directory and include the following file

If any file is a directory then it is processed recursively.
The manifest file name, the archive file name and the entry point name are
specified in the same order as the 'm', 'f' and 'e' flags.

Example 1: to archive two class files into an archive called classes.jar:  

       jar cvf classes.jar Foo.class Bar.class
Example 2: use an existing manifest file 'mymanifest' and archive all the
           files in the `foo/ directory into 'classes.jar'`:

       jar cvfm classes.jar mymanifest -C foo/ .
```

Comment: The trick is to read the message, which explains what you must do.

Comment: I've reformatted this question and found it is all console output. We prefer it if questions contain _some_ of your own words, explaining what the problem is and what you have tried.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to add all files then use :

```
jar -cvf scholarship.war *.*
```

Comment: @Gopalan: I am assuming this is the correct answer. Please click the tick mark to the left if so. Since you did not reply to Pankaj, I will downvote your question, but will happily undownvote once you reply to me (either to accept the question or to explain that this is not the answer).

Comment: I got same issue and this is correct solution, solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

The error message says it all: you are not telling jar which files should go in the archive. If you want to add everything under the current directory use

```
jar cf scholarship.war *
```

Comment: i  created the project using jsp and servlet in netbeans. the project folder is saved in documents/netbeans project/scholarship. i know war file is created in netbeans. but .i want to create war file manually

Answer (score 2):

Structure your files according to [the standard war layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/packaging003.htm) in a directory, say *.package* and then type:

```
cd .package; jar cvf ../package.war *
```

You should now be able to drop the war into any container and activate the web application.

Comment: hi friend ,C:\Users\accer\Documents\NetBeansProjects\.  all my projects are saved inside the netbeansprojects folder. i dont know how to package it. i need your help

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with netbeans you can do it with this path:

Project Properties -> Build -> Packaging -> Build JAR after compiling

Comment: thanks zao, but i need to create manually using command prompt