# How to create a WAR file using the commandline?

Tags: maven, jboss, war, pom.xml, siesta

I installed JBoss Developer Studio and it's possible to create a WAR file by "right mouse project > Export > WAR file" but I want to export my project to a WAR file using the commandline.

I have maven installed which is one of the requirements of the Studio and I read that I can generate a WAR file using maven but I require a file called pom.xml. When I searched through my workspace and project, pom.xml was missing. I may need to manually create pom.xml but I'm unsure how to.

My directory tree for my project is the following:

```
Siesta
├── build
│   └── classes
├── src
└── WebContent
    ├── extjs
    ├── extjs-4.2.0
    ├── extjs-4.2.2
    ├── index.jsp
    ├── META-INF
    ├── siesta
    ├── tests
    └── WEB-INF
```

How do I create a WAR file for my Maven / JBoss project using the command line? I use Linux and would prefer not having to create a pom.xml file but if there isn't another way, then I'll use the xml file to generate the war file.

**Edit:**

So jar is the way to go to create a war file. I wrote up a tiny script that will create a war file for me for a specific directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Siesta/WebContent/
jar -cvf ../../Siesta.war *
cd -
```

Then if you open the war file in a zip utility or archive manager in ubuntu, you'll see this structure

```
    ├── extjs
    ├── extjs-4.2.0
    ├── extjs-4.2.2
    ├── index.jsp
    ├── META-INF
    ├── siesta
    ├── tests
    └── WEB-INF
```

I have to CD into the directory that I want to create a war file of which is kind of annoying. I think there may be a better way to do it using jar's -C option but when I used "jar -cvf Siesta.war -C Siesta/WebContent *" it didn't have the same result.

**Edit2:**

```
jar -cvf my-app.war myfolder/
```

For my application to work on TomCat, I use the following:

```
cd Siesta/WebContent
jar -cvf Siesta.war *
```

Comment: this is so easy.  Why does everyone talk about eclipse and maven and pom files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright here is a already existing SO with a couple of possibilities on how to create a war file: [How to create war files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001714/how-to-create-war-files).

I personaly prefer Maven over any other build scenario - Since i migrated from ANT i did not like Maven in the first place but after investing like a day or two into the documentations: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html i started to love it. In your case all you need is refactor your project to meet the maven standard file structure and create a minimum Maven project (a.k.a. `pom.xml` file) for your sources that has the packaging `war` instead of the default `jar`.

If you want to stick with the console only and dont use any build helpers beside the ones delivered by the JDK you can create your war with something like this:

`jar cvf my-app.war`

Have a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html for a complete reference of the supported options.

(Note: A "war" in the context of java based web applications follows a standard format: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaby.html while the technical ".war" file is just the same as a ZIP compressed folder renamed to ".zip".)

(Also note i would realy take the time to get in touch with maven since after that you know about a serious build tool and will be able to create `jar`, `ear`, `war` etc. in a standard process).

Comment: Interesting, so you're that using "jar cvf my-app.war" will create my .war file or if TomCat just needs a .war zip file, then all I need to do is zip the directory's contents. Let me try that.

Comment: @SomeGuyOnAComputer well i havent tested the jar tool to be honest. But yes if you follow the WAR-directory layout and have a working webapplication inside that structure (could be a single `index.html` file in `/WEB-INF/`) you can just ZIP that folder and rename the resulting ZIP to a WAR and deploy that on your local Tomcat

Comment: I tried the zip method and unfortunately that didn't work. However the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342075/generate-war-file-from-tomcat-webapp-folder uses exactly what you put above "jar -cvf my-app.war myfolder/" and that did the trick!

Answer (score 7):

If this is a **Maven** project, then open your console, navigate to where the *pom.xml* file is and then run:

```
mvn package
```

It will create the *{artifactId}-{version}.war* file under **${basedir}/target** directory. This assumes that your `packaging` POM element is set to `war` in your *pom.xml* file.

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    ...
</project>
```

> Some of the valid packaging values are **jar**, **war**, **ear** and **pom**. If no packaging value has been specified, it will default to **jar**.

More details [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) and [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html).

Comment: With all these options: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, 
generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, 
test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, 
clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy ... package is the one I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest choice (if you are using Maven) is to create it with the maven-archetype-webapp:

```
 mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.sample -DartifactId=web-project -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

You can then refine your pom.xml to include the dependencies required, for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Source: [How to create a Web application from the Command Line](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/jboss-maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-from-the-command-line/)