# How to create a war file for my java web application project from terminal without using eclipse

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I have a java web application project (maven) that I want to serve on a tomcat server. I want to create a .war file from it so then I can place it in the webapps directory.I know that from eclipse I can to do it by the export but I need to do it through terminal. also I have tried the `jar cvf example.war *` command but when I put the war file inside the webapps directory tomcat cant read my java application.
Can someone please guide me on how to create a war file from terminal that tomcat can read it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245567/how-to-create-a-war-file-using-the-commandline

Comment: Hey Sandeep no its not because I have tried the jar command

Comment: `cd /to/your/folder/location`; `jar -cvf my_web_app.war *` didn't worked for you?

Comment: This is creating a war file but Tomcat cant recognize it when I place it in the webapps

Comment: Use `mvn package` on the directory that has `pom.xml`

Comment: hey Raphael this created a jar file for me. I have added the `<packaging>war</packaging>` in my pom.xml but then it complain that the webxml attribute is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pom.xml, add the following line

```
<packaging>war</packaging>    // Replace <packaging>jar</packaging> if jar packaging already present
```

And then go to the parent directory of the project and enter `mvn package`. war file will be generated in

```
/parent_directory/target/myproject.war
```

If you want to access your project as `http://localhost:8080` rather than `http://localhost:8080/myproject`, rename `myproject.war` to `ROOT.war` and paste the war file in webapps of tomcat directory.

Comment: This was the solution that I came up with. Also if anyone else get the error about the web.xml you should add these attributes to your pom.xml.
`<build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <webXml>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>`

Answer (score 0):

### Steps:

- Navigate to an appropriate directory(let's say desktop) and use `maven-archetype-webapp` to start a simple webapp maven project. For example:

  mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mywebapp.www -DartifactId=MyWebApp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp

[image]

See: **[Introduction to Maven Archetypes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html)**

- Once your project is created, navigate to the directory which has the `pom.xml` and use:

  mvn package

[image]

- Once you are done with step 2, navigate to the `target` directory where you would find a `MyWebApp.war` generated.
- Copy-paste `MyWebApp.war` to tomcat `webapps` directory and start the tomcat server(`./startup.sh`).
- As you can see, we can now access the URL `http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/`.

[image]

For your reference -

### index.jsp:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

### pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mywebapp.www</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyWebApp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1</version>
  <name>MyWebApp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>MyWebApp</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Hope that helps.