# Create WAR file from command line for Eclipse Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, command, war

I got a problem with generating a war file from a dynamic web project by the command line. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340190/how-to-create-a-war-file-for-my-java-web-application-project-from-terminal-witho) thread. But unfortunately I dont have maven or gradle...

If I create a war file from commandline from the main directory of my Webproject, I cant connect on any website by tomcat. If I go deeper into folder "webcontent", I am able to connect to the html welcome-page but I am not able to connect to the servlets, which are located in the src folder.
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Would Ant be an option?

Comment: You don't currently have gradle or maven. But can you add one of them to your project? Gradle, for example, can be distributed in a form of a self-contained [wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html), that doesn't require anything other that JDK installed in the system.

Comment: Thanks you too. I already tried it with Ant but had some trouble to create the war file with it. Now I am trying to convert it into a maven project. I think it would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I solved the problem with a different solution:

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290029/http-status-404-on-eclipse-with-tomcat) thread, I created /WEB-INF/classes under /WebContent.

Then I was able to create the War-File really easy with

```
cd /to/your/Webcontent/directory
jar -cvf /destination/folder/of/war-file *
```

And deployed this war file in tomcat. Everything working now. Hope this will also help other people with similar problem.