# How to deploy a Java Web application

Tags: java, spring, deployment, web-deployment

I'm developping a web application on Eclipse with Spring Boot/Security/Web/DataJPA and my boss want to deploy it on a server to make it reachable by browser everywhere. How I can do that ? I have no skills of networks and deploiement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your Eclipse project, right-click on the name of the project and select "Export". Then, generate a .war file. In any java-enabled web server, you can use its web manager interface to deploy the site using the generated .war file. It is very easy.

Comment: Thnaks. It is not possible to use a maven command ?

Comment: Yeah. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245567/how-to-create-a-war-file-using-the-commandline

Answer (score 1):

i have answer but "How to deploy a Java Web application on tomcat"
first
   Copying web application archive file (.war).
second
   Copying unpacked web application directory.
third step
    Using Tomcat’s manager application.

Comment: Hello. Thanks. I thinks I'll use tomcat :).