# deploy webapp running in tomcat5 into tomcat7

Tags: linux, tomcat, solaris

we have an instance of tomcat running on solaris 10 version 5. we do not have a war file  or anything..

I installed a new server linux centOS and i am try to deploy the app on this new server..

we do not have any war file since the app is very old running without issue since 2005 but due to some component deprecating tls 1.0 we need to adapt it and we take the opportunity to instal in a more recent version.

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342075/generate-war-file-from-tomcat-webapp-folder

Comment: unfortunately the webapp folder is empty.. so I cannot apply that. I had already found that suggestion and looked into it

Comment: I'm confused, but that's probably just me:)  I saw that you said "the app is very old running without issue since 2005".  You're saying that the app isn't under the webapps folder in your old Tomcat 5 instance -- so how can it have been running there since 2005?