# How to deploy web app to tomcat without eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

To my knowledge, to deploy my web application to tomcat, I need to move the war file under webapps in tomcat home. And in eclipse, in order to do that I right click on the server and select "Add and Remove", then add the projects to deploy them when ran.

Without eclipse, I have to make the war file myself by using `jar -cf projectname.war *` but I don't at which directory should I use this command. Also, should I compile all the sources in the src folder first?

To sum up my question, what is the step to run my web app on tomcat without using eclipse? I want to know what eclipse have done for me under the hood.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate war file from tomcat webapp folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342075/generate-war-file-from-tomcat-webapp-folder)

Comment: What about whether I need to compile the java files first? Also I need to deploy multiple projects?

Comment: Yes, you need. Use some building tool, e.g. Maven, and read a tutorial (google for `maven web application development`). You can start with https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_web_application.htm